# cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 60) is not working in python manage.py shell

Tags: python, django

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 60)
cache.get('my_key')
```

What can be the reason that `get()` does not print anything. Is the problem with `set()` or `get()`.

Comment: Can you post your CACHE settings ?

Comment: CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': [
            '127.0.0.1:11211'
        ]
    }
}

Comment: i have restarted memcached and now it is working. thank you for the help